# Parse serialized string of protobuf message from C++ in Java failed

Tags: java, c++, protocol-buffers

C++ code writing the message:

```
std::string result;
message.SerializeToString(&result);
```

Java code parsing the message:

```
InputStream targetStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(result.getBytes());
DefinedProto instance = DefinedProto.parseDelimitedFrom(targetStream);
```

But it turned out this error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.protobuf.CodedInputStream.shouldDiscardUnknownFields()Z
```

I think I'm using the same version of protoc in C++ and Java. Does anyone know how to parse protobuf message from C++ serialized string (bytes)?

Comment: You serialize the message to the `result` string, but how do you send `result`? Do you send `result`?

Comment: @user4581301I send the result by kafka, so I recover the string by parsing byte array from kafka using new String(byte[]).